# how to create writable and searchable dropdown list in my asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to create writable and searchable drop down list in my asp.net using c#

my drop down as follows...

Hyderabad
                             Warangal
                             Kakinada
                              ongole
                             vizag
                             guntur

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: thanks for ur reply yes i tried it with ajax ListSearchExtender also but it is not giving any typed text in my drop down i think i have to add text box to my drop down how can i?

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of good solutions out of the box, like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Check them.